# can't reload page again with router link

Tags: javascript, vue.js

As you can see, there's a list that send itself as params to routerlink. When i click that

it works fine, but when I click another

again, it doesn't change the page. Guide me with this

This is in Router.js

```
{
  path: '/works/:sort_id',
  name: 'WorksView',
  component: WorksView,
 }
```

this is in nav.vue

```
        <ul v-for="(nav, index) in navSorts" :key="index">
            <router-link :to=" {name: 'WorksView', params: {sort_id: nav.title}}"><p>{{ nav.title }}</p></router-link>
            <li  v-for="(sort, index) in nav.sort" :key="index">
              <router-link :to=" {name: 'WorksView', params: {sort_id: sort}}"><p>{{ sort }}</p></router-link>
            </li>
          </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case Vue router does not change the route but only params.
It won't cause re-creation of component.
You can force re-render of specific part of your template with `:key` prop.

For example

```
<some-component :key="$route.params.sortId">
```

Or use [Watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) to handle route params change and do some stuff, for example fetch request with new sort param. Example with route params [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes).

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot